# What could cause memory corruption in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, memory-corruption

I am developing an application which uses TinyMCE editors to allow the user to modify content. I have developed a Prototype.js class which, upon initialization, generates a unique ID and creates a TinyMCE editor on a `<div>` with that ID. Here's some of the relevant code:

```
Region = Class.create(
{
  initialize: function(options)
  {
    this._editorReady = false;
    this._index = Region.nextIndex++;
    this._uid = com.digitalfruition.Customizer.TypeRegion.uidPrefix+this._index;
    Region.instances.push(this);
    this.setupTinyMCE();
  },

  uid: function()
  {
    return this._uid;
  },

  index: function()
  {
    return this._index;
  },
```

In a lot of places, I will refer to a `Region`'s `uid()`, for example, when events occur within the TinyMCE editor (for example, the selection changes) my handlers are given the ID of the editor. I will often do:

```
var index = Region.instances.invoke('uid').indexOf(uid);
```

To find the actual `Region` instance reflecting the interface the events occurred in.

**I only ever set the `_uid` property of any given `Region` once**. I'm sure of this.

But in Firefox 9.0.1, I am seeing really odd behavior. When events fire, the editor they're firing on can't be found because `index` in the code above is `-1`. After inspecting in Firebug, I saw this:

[image: Screen Capture of odd behavior]

Those are debug messages from my code, logging various things (the height of the regions in this case) along with the region's `this.uid()` value. **The memory appears to have gotten corrupted!** and you can even see where it happens, the first circled log entry is correct, and the subsequent ones are wrong.

The same code works fine in Safari and Chrome. So far only Firefox 9.0.1 seems to be affected...

To inspect further, I ran this in the Firebug console:

```
>>> com.digitalfruition.Customizer.TypeRegion.instances.invoke('uid');
["�ᔮ��蒦ᓤ�瀀魳ᓪ�倀⛺ᓪ�怀�eg����遀"]
```

That makes no sense to me. What could cause memory corruption like this in JavaScript? How do I even go about troubleshooting such a situation?

Comment: I'm in [the JavaScript chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) in case you want to ask me any questions!

Comment: Where does this 'com.digitalfruition.Customizer.TypeRegion' thing come from, by the way?  Is it a pure JavaScript object?

Comment: @dyoo Sorry, that isn't clear, is it? :) That's the Region object in my code sample; I just shortened the code for my question.

Comment: Have you tried deactivating any and all plugins/addins/extensions ? Tried in a separate user account/other machine ? This should not happen in pure JS =/

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that one of your files is saved with a different encoding? I'd look at that, and also maybe make sure you're serving the files with the correct encoding and mime types.

It might be a good idea to do some testing where you `console.log()` the `uid` values as they are generated to confirm that the corruption is in fact occurring after the objects are created. I suspect it's happening when they are created.

Comment: I'm positive no encodings have changed... good thought though!

Comment: Also, the corruption definitely occurs after the objects are created. Those log messages occur after the objects are created and you can even see *three* different values in the screen capture I showed. So they're changing afterwards.

Comment: Hmmm. Have you tested in Chrome to confirm that it's just a Firefox issue?

Comment: Any other libraries in the mix besides Prototype.js and TinyMCE? Might be worth playing with the [TinyMCE demo](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/baaaab) in Firefox to see if you can get anything similar to happen. Also, try hardcoding a small set of objects to see if they still get corrupted.

Comment: Good ideas Josh. There are a few other libraries on this page. I'll disable them and see if that causes the issue. Hardcoding a specific example may be the only way I can track this down, but that's less than ideal as this is a small part of a 5444+ line JavaScript application!

Comment: Ugh. From one Josh to another... :) I think the best thing you can do is start to peel back layers until you're able to get a minimal reproduction. That TinyMCE control looks pretty complex, so it seems likely that there's a bug in there somewhere.